Looking for a tiling shader node
I'm looking for a shader node which can repeat a procedural black and white pattern in a tile layout, and allows the tiles to be transformed individually. I wonder if there is a simple way to do this since I'm trying to make my own shader using OSL. One drawback of using a script node for doing this is that the function used to create the procedural pattern has to be written in the script and, as far as I know, cannot be given as an argument to the tiling shader.
Does someone have a clue ? Maybe using a brick texture node ?
Thanks

For sure, rectangular tiling, you can do on your own with Wrap .. or by using a non-random Voronoi. The only question is what you mean by: 'tiles transformed individually' .. randomly? by some math function? manipulating some attribute of the mesh by hand?

Thank you for your answer. Yes they would be transformed by a random scale, rotation, and translation vector so some tiles could overlap each other.

But would you like to be able to edit targeted individual tiles, picked randomly or by you, or have them be randomly selected, or through some other means?

They wouldn't be picked, all the tiles would have a random transform.
